# RegisterComposablePartCatalog throws error not available

Tags: autofac, mef

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'ContainerBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'RegisterComposablePartCatalog' and no accessible extension method 'RegisterComposablePartCatalog' accepting a first argument of type 'ContainerBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

using .net core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Composable part catalogs are MEF, not Autofac. If you're using the Autofac/MEF integration, you're likely missing the `using Autofac.Integration.Mef;` line at the top of your code.

Comment: If it worked, please accept my answer so I can get credit for helping you. Thanks!